# First-order logic from computational linguistics - implication

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, mathematical-modeling, logic-translation

I am reading Natural Language Understanding by James Allen.

It has the following sentence

```
That John is rich implies that he is happy.
```

And first-order logic representation as

RICH(JOHN1) $\supset$ HAPPY(JOHN1)

I think it is incorrect and should be written as

RICH(JOHN1) $\subset$ HAPPY(JOHN1)

since rich only subset, there are probably other things that make John happy.

I am quite confident that it is not a typo, but why it is written this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) is often used in formal logic to translate "if..., then...".

Thus, "That John is rich implies that he is happy" is the same as : "if John is rich, then he is happy".

"If..., then..." is symbolized with the [conditional connective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#List_of_common_logical_connectives) : $\to, \supset, \Rightarrow$.

---

The symbol $\subset$ is used for the relation of *inclusion* between sets (or : classes).

In that cases we have e.g. : $\text {Humans} \subset \text {Animals}$.

But $\text {Rich}(\text{John})$ is not the name of a class; it is a sentence : "John is rich".

Comment: Thank you! It would be so much easier to use arrow notation than superset/subset notation

Comment: @user1700890: It is not only easier, it is **standard**. The only ones still using "⊃" are woefully outdated philosophers who mostly don't even understand basic logic facts from Godel onwards.